# Constraints or Trigger

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers, constraints

I am in a really hot spot here,

I have two tables

1. `MonthlyPayment` (`EmpID, PaymentType, swiftcode`)
2. `EmpAssignment` (`EmpID, status`)

`EmpAssignment.Status` can only be 1 or 2

The question is:

I would like a constraint or trigger, such that on update of `MonthlyPayment`, if `PaymentType = 1` then `Swiftcode` should be unique and mandatory only for those whose `status = 1`.

If `PaymentType <> 1`, `swiftcode` should not be mandatory but unique
Also, the constraint should not affect those whose `status = 2`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What RDBMS and version?

Comment: Third option: create a `DOMAIN` and make status use that domain.

Comment: So, `swiftcode` should always be unique (across all rows), provided it's not `null`?

Comment: The constraint on `EmpAssignment.Status` will need a `check` constraint if you are using an RDBMS like Oracle or SQL Server. Otherwise put a trigger for that. For the other constraint you are talking, it is outside the scope of built-in constraint types of most RDBMS, so you will need to set up a trigger for that.

Comment: Am using SQl Server 2008, Yes SwiftCode should always be unique

Answer (score 1):

Using domains, the constraint would become a domain constraint:

```
DROP DOMAIN PAYTYPE CASCADE;
CREATE DOMAIN PAYTYPE AS INTEGER
    CHECK (value >= 1 AND value <= 666)
    ;

DROP DOMAIN ESTATUS CASCADE;
CREATE DOMAIN ESTATUS AS INTEGER
    CHECK (value >= 1 AND value <= 2)
    ;

DROP TABLE MonthlyPayment CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE MonthlyPayment
    ( EmpID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    , PaymentType PAYTYPE NOT NULL
    , swiftcode varchar
    );

DROP TABLE EmpAssignment CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE EmpAssignment
    ( EmpID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    , status ESTATUS NOT NULL
    );
```

Now test it:

```
 INSERT INTO EmpAssignment(EmpID,status) VALUES(1,9);
```

Result (using Postgresql-9.1):

```
ERROR:  value for domain estatus violates check constraint "estatus_check"
```

Comment: Looking at the OP's previous questions this is likely to be useless to them as they are on SQL Server but +1.

Comment: OP did not mention a platform. domain is in ANSI, iirc. Oracle and postgres have them, so microsoft and sybase could, too.

Comment: Yes SQL Server could have them. [But it doesn't](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739783/implement-real-domains)

Comment: BTW: now I read the OQ again, and conclude that the OP actually wants a cross-field constraint, even a cross-table constraint. (I do not understand why there are two separate tables, BTW) That would imply trigger trickery, maybe even a third table with allowed and valid combinations. When in the same table, a partial index would be sufficient.

Comment: @wildplasser: No, Oracle does not have domains.

Comment: Oops. I stand corrected. (I do need to reread some manuals ;-)